# Is it possible that host would not allow for Android to get a file?

Tags: java, android, connection

I want to parse some external XML files and for that I need `InputStream`. So I defined and validated my url:

```
String Url = "http://www..............................................xml";
URL validUrl = new URL(Url.toString().trim().replaceAll(" ", "%20"));
```

And then I tried a lot of variants:
First:

```
object = XmlParser.parseMthod(validUrl.openStream());
```

Second:

```
object = XmlParser.parseMthod(validUrl.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

Third:

```
URLConnection connection = validUrl.openConnection();
HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)connection;
httpConn.setDoInput(true);
httpConn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
object = XmlParser.parseMthod(httpConn.getInputStream());
```

They end up in catch outputting `null` as an error description... So it got me wondering could it be my host's or my emulator's fault?

No have not forgotten to include Internet privileges for the app:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Most of the times error returned would be null but ounce I received:

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Comment: Does your app have INTERNET permissions in your config?

Comment: >They end up in catch
:What catch?  There's no try or catch in the code you included.

Comment: I have not included try catch because it is mandatory if method does not throw needed exceptions  .

Comment: we understand, but if it ends up with an exception and you're catching that exception, can you tell us what the type and message is for the exception?